# How do I count the number of unique values across multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, unique, distinct-values, across

I have a large dataset - 23500 rows.  Every row has doublets of events and I need to count the unique events. So I need to count unique events across 30 columns for each row - and create a new column for each row with the count. How to do this the easiest way?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the row, get the `unique` elements and find the `length` in `base R`

```
df1$new <- apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x[complete.cases(x)])))
```

---

Or another option is `rowwise` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(new = n_distinct(c_across(everything()), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(new = pmap_dbl(select(cur_data(), everything()), ~ n_distinct(c(...), na.rm = TRUE)))
```